# Dexnav Shiny Chaining tutoral?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

So, I've already completed the Elite Four 5 times and the champion, and now I hear about Dexnav Chaining. I know that its not just for shinies but for IVS and im mainly going for shinies. Does anyone have a good tutorial on *how to do this?*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/DexNav#Chaining) explains it pretty well:

> Every time the player encounters a hidden Pokémon of any species for any reason, the chain increases. As the chain increases, the Pokémon have a greater chance of having any of the special attributes (IVs, eggmoves, hidden ability, higher level and item held).
>
> The chance of encountering a **Shiny Pokémon** also increases, estimated to reach 0.5% per encounter after 40 chained encounters, and remain at that rate as long as the chain continues. There is thus a 50% chance of encountering a Shiny Pokémon in the first (roughly) 130 chained encounters.
> A chain is broken when the player leaves the area (including entering a building), encounters a wild Pokémon that isn't hidden, or moves too quickly and scares away a hidden Pokémon. Hidden Pokémon can be encountered for a chain either with or without the Search function. Getting the message "*The Pokémon couldn't be found. Try looking in a different area!*" when using the Search function does not break the chain.

Here's a good video tutorial:

Comment: I've recently stumbled upon [this look into the game code](http://mrnbayoh.github.io/pkmn6gen/dexnav_shiny/), which I found very interesting. Simply put, chaining does not increase the chances for a shiny Pokémon except on the 50th and 100th encounter in a chain, while the overall encounter level increases the chances of a shiny whilst using the DexNav.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I have to read that article, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

While in Pokemon X/Y you could chain encounters to increase the likelihood of running into shiny Pokemon, it appears that using the DexNav in Omega Ruby / Alpha Sapphire confers a flat bonus to your likelihood of running into shinies, regardless of how many encounters you've "chained".

So **DexNav shiny chaining is not a thing**. You do have a higher chance of running into shiny Pokemon if you use the DexNav, and it does appear that the shiny Pokemon encountered *do* have higher IVs if you chain encounters using DexNav, though.

Source: [DexNav analysis on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemon/comments/2o6we0/data_analysis_on_dexnav_chaining_and_shiny_pokemon/)

Comment: Im pretty sure there is chaining, so that's why im following the answer previous to this one by @pinckerman . I don't know what Reddit is believing, because I watched a guy who caught Shinies on several *chains*